# how to non-rectangular bitmaps

Tags: android

am writing a swap faces sort of app. Thus far on the given image the faces are detected and I can even swap them by their rectangular coordinates. But when swapping them I do it with the use of rectangulars. Which is not good because our face are not rectangular.

So how can I swap 2 rectangulars on the bitmap so they would at least look oval or even better by using a facial mask to carve them out?

Comment: The bitmaps would still be rectangular, but you can define the shape of the face (e.g. oval) and fill the remainder of the rectangle with the transparent colour.

Comment: how would I go about doing this?

Comment: I'm guessing, you define the bounding rectangle and take that rectangle as the bitmap. Then you define the polygon or ellipse for the shape of the face and fill the outside of it with transparent paint.

Comment: sounds good in theory. Could you mesh up some code so I would even know how to begin?